# Use variable across multiple Cpp files

Tags: c++, scope, header-files, ld, extern

Have searched enough answers but none of the solutions work for me.

scenario :
I am trying to include a .h file that has some functions declared (not defined) and some variables declared.

If I include this header file in the source files (2 to be precise) that actually use the functions and variables, then the last one that compiles has a linker error that states

> undefined reference to `abc::myfun(char const*, char const*, char*)'

All the functions and variables in the header files have been declared as extern and include guards are present.

I wish to have one cpp file put a value in the variable defined in the .h file and another cpp file to be able to read it.

Also if it helps, every piece of my code is in a namespace that I have defined ( `namespace abc{ //all my code, in all the files }` )

Comment: First, does at least one source file define the variable/function?  Are you including that in the link?  Second, do you include your headers *outside* of the namespace?  You don't want to inadvertently nest - *ie* `abc::abc::something`

Comment: specifically `abc::myfun(char const*, char const*, char*)` as noted from your error seems to be at least one culprit.  Could you posted the declaration from your header file and where it is defined in a source file?

Answer (score 3):

Declarations in your `.h` file are doing exactly that - letting compiler know *of* the objects you are planning on *declaring* "somewhere". That "somewhere" would be a compilation unit (a `.c` or `.cpp` file) where that variable would be **defined**.

Here's an example (skipping the guards for simplicity):

`foo.h`:

```
extern int global_foo;
```

`foo.c`:

```
#include "foo.h"
int global_foo; // optionally you can initialize like this: int global_foo = 123;
```

`main.c`:

```
#include "foo.h"
void bar()
{
  global_foo = 0; // accessing that variable which is "outside" of this file
```

As paddy mentioned above - make sure you are not accidentally nesting namespaces, since `abc::something` is not the same as `abc::abc::something`

Comment: but this isnt working , it still says that the variables and functions have undefined reference

Comment: could you distill your problem into a short-ish code sample and provide it along with the error you are getting? (and a command-line you use for building)

Answer (score 0):

Your error seems to be with `abc::myfun(char const*, char const*, char*)`.  I was able to reproduce and confirm this.  Without the second part you'll get the error.

I'm guessing you have a header file something like

```
namespace abc 
{
    void myfun(char const* p1, char const* p2, char* p3);
}
```

and a .cpp source file needs

```
namespace abc
{
    void myfun(char const* p1, char const* p2, char* p3)
    {
        // do fun stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: @VenushreePatel Hmm, I'm afraid I'll need to see your code to diagnose further.